# Form input values are empty after submit

Tags: wp-admin, forms, options

I'm trying to build a settings page for my WordPress theme. I have created the following form which includes repeatable input fields. Everything is working except when I submit the form and refresh the page it shows me for example 3 inputs but with empty values. (Values are in the DB)

```
function fr_render_form() { ?>
        <div class="wrap">

                <div class="icon32" id="icon-options-general"><br></div>
                <h2>Options</h2>

                <form method="post" action="options.php">
                        <?php $options = get_option('fr_options'); ?>

                        <table class="form-table">

                               <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="repeatable-add button" href="#">+</a>
                                    <ul id="tracks-repeatable-repeatable" class="custom_repeatable">
                                 <?php 
                                  if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {
                                        $i = 1;
                                        foreach( $options as $option ) {
                                            ?> <li>
                                            <input type="text" name="fr_options[txt_<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $options['fr_options'.$i]; ?>" />
                                            <a class="repeatable-remove button" href="#">-</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <?php
                                            $i++;
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        ?> <li>
                                        <input type="text" name="fr_options[txt_1]" value="<?php echo $options['txt_1']; ?>" />
                                         <a class="repeatable-remove button" href="#">-</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <?php
                                    } ?>
                                    </ul><a class="repeatable-add button" href="#">+</a> 
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                        <p class="submit">
                        <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
                        </p>
                </form>

        </div>
        <?php  
}
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked whether the options are successfully saved in the database when the form is submitted? If they're there, have you done a `var_dump($options)` to see how it's formatted? Perhaps it's a serialized array or some other format you're not expecting?

Comment: @WebElaine thank you for the reply, it returns `Array ( [txt_1] => hi1 [txt_2] => hi2 [txt_3] => hi3 [txt_4] => hi4 [txt_5] => hi5 [txt_6] => hi6 [txt_7] => hi7 [txt_8] => hi8) `

Comment: There's your trouble. You're trying to echo `$options['fr_options'.$i]` when you need to echo `$options['txt_' . $i]`.

Comment: @WebElaine Thank you so much!